# Eigen values of a matrix depending on k

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & k \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$. Find all values of $k$ for which A has eigenvalues 3 and -1. A has no real eigenvalues. (David Poole, Linear Algebra).

The characteristic equation $(2 - \lambda)(1 - \lambda) = 0$ doesn't depend on $k$, so is this ever true? What am I missing here?

Comment: There might be typo in your matrix $A$; the lower left corner is $1$ and not $0$.

Comment: Well, that seems to be the best logical conclusion. Textbook typos hurt bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix you wrote down always has two eigenvalues, $2$ and $1$.